How to cook indomie brand instant noodles in an electric kettle after in has been soaked in warm water with the seasoning
Like yesterday when I was cooking indomie in an electric kettle.the current was not stable so when the water was a bit hot I added the seasoning and the light in the kettle went off so I added the indomie fingers crossed it will come out well cos the current like I said was not stable but few minutes later the power went off completely from the whole building and my indomie still in the water . Though I drained the water and poured out the indomie in an open plate ️ but I am still worried  if the indomie will turn out well judging firm the fact that it soaked water

I had to look up 'Indomie' and found that it's a brand of instant noodle. Aren't you meant to pour boiling water onto the noodles in a bowl rather than putting them into your kettle?

As per this answer, pasta and noodles* don't need boiling water to cook, merely water that's over about 80ºC.  (I guess instant noodles start from boiling water coz that's easy to prepare and stays above 80ºC for long enough to cook fully.)  (* In my country, ‘pasta’ and ‘noodles’ are separate and distinct, though the temperature presumably applies to both.)  So the question is: how long were your noodles over 80ºC?

@KateBunting Indomie say simmer for 3 minutes (luckily I had an odd pack left - they're among the better instant noodles so I have them for camping and when I get in from a long ride). Cooking them in a kettle is a known hack for people without proper cooking facilities - not one I've tried, but I think I can come up with an answer

@gidds instant noodles can be revived with three minutes of steaming, as well.  you're just softening the pre-cooked and then fried noodles

I have a pack of Indomie here, and they say they should be simmered for 3 minutes.  But that's not really necessary.  I usually pour over boiling water,  cover, and wait 5 minutes. They're done then.
Just as an aside: When people cook them in a kettle, generally they add the seasoning to the bowl, not the kettle.  The salt and oil in the seasoning isn't good for your kettle, and taints other things made using water boiled in the same kettle.  Personally if I wanted noodles soft and really hot in a hotel room or student dorm, I still wouldn't put them in the kettle, but pour boiling water over them, wait until they're nearly soft, drain, pour more boiling water on them and then add the seasoning.
Ramen-type instant noodles are pre-cooked so really all you have to do is soften them enough to be palatable.  Apparently some people even like to eat them cold and hard, straight out of the packet!
That means that if they're soft enough to eat, and hot enough to enjoy (both thresholds which may depend on your hunger and budget), go ahead.
However if you left them sitting in warm water for hours waiting for the power to come back on, it's not a good idea from the point of view of food safety.

I second not cooking them in the kettle, there's oil in the actual noodles, even if you don't add the flavor packet to the kettle you're still going to get noodle flavored coffee and tea.

Good point @GdD - the precooking involves frying so that will deliver oil.  And if this is in a hotel, you're spoiling the kettle for the next person
